# I accidentally did something in Destiny and now I'm "Fireteam Leader". How do I leave it?

Tags: destiny

I basically don't know how to leave or abandon fireteam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're in the Tower, you should be able to leave by simply pressing **SELECT** then **X** (on Xbox) or the **Trackpad** and **Square** (on Playstation).

In orbit, however, you should just be able to press **B** or **Circle**.

Comment: When I press my trackpad and square nothing happens. There is only one option. (triangle - go to orbit)

Comment: Try pressing **OPTIONS**, then look at the **Roster** menu. Can you interact with the players in the "Fireteam" list?

Comment: Also, if you are on a mission (planet-bound), you can go to orbit, then abandon the fireteam that way

Comment: I am the only one in the Fireteam list :/

Comment: @GloomyPlatypus Then that means you don't have a Fireteam to leave. If you invite people to your game, you will be the Leader, but if your join *their* game, you will not.

Comment: but when i go to roster it says "fireteam leader" on my character.

Comment: @GloomyPlatypus That's irrelevant really. When you don't have a Fireteam, you're placed as the leader by default.